# How to give a unique id for each cell when adding custom columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote following code to add a custom column to my table. but i want to add a unique id to each cell in those columns. the format should be a(column no)(cell no>)
ex :- for the column no 4 :- a41, a42, a43, ........
So please can anyone tell me how to do that. Thank You!

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
     var myform = $('#myform'),
         iter = 4;

     $('#btnAddCol').click(function () {
         myform.find('tr').each(function(){
           var trow = $(this);
           var colName = $("#txtText").val();
           if (colName!="")
           {
             if(trow.index() === 0){
                 //trow.append('<td>'+iter+'</td>');
                 $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td>'+colName+iter+'</td>');
             }else{
                 //trow.append('<td><input type="text" name="al'+iter+'"/></td>');
                 $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td><input type="text" id="a'+iter+'" name="a'+iter+'"/></td>');
             }
            } 
         });
         iter += 1;
     });
 });
```

Comment: Why not just add an inner iterator? Another option is to use jquery ui's `.uniqueId()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have code that's modifying the contents of the table (adding cells), which argues fairly strongly against adding an `id` to every cell, or at least one based on its row/column position, as you have to *change* them when you add cells to the table.

But if you really want to do that, after your modifications, run a nested loop and assign the `id`s using the indexes passed into `each`, overwriting any previous `id` they may have had:

```
myform.find("tr").each(function(row) {
    $(this).find("td").each(function(col) {
        this.id = "a" + row + col;
    });
});
```

(Note that this assumes no nested tables.)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(trow.index() === 0){
   //trow.append('<td>'+iter+'</td>');
   $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td id="a'+column_no+cell_no+'">'+colName+iter+'</td>');
}else{
   //trow.append('<td><input type="text" name="al'+iter+'"/></td>');
   $(this).find('td').eq(5).after('<td id="a'+column_no+cell_no+'"><input type="text" id="a'+iter+'" name="a'+iter+'"/></td>');
}
```

you just have to define and iterate the column_no and cell_no variable

Answer (score 0):

When all other cells are numbered consistently (for example using a `data-attribute` with value rXcX), you could use something like:

```
function addColumn(){
   $('table tr').each( 
          function(i, row) {
              var nwcell = $('<td>'), previdx;
              $(row).append(nwcell);
              previdx = nwcell.prev('td').attr('data-cellindex');
              nwcell.attr('data-cellindex',
                          previdx.substr(0,previdx.indexOf('c')+1)
                          + (+previdx.substr(-previdx.indexOf('c'))+1));
          });
}
```

Worked out in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/Vwy6m/)